# Show logs written with EventLog.writeEvent in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-log

In Android Studio how do I view logs written using the

```
EventLog.writeEvent(5,"WHY CANT I SEE THIS");
```

The reason being I want to monitor system events being written by the platform itself and according to the source it's using EventLog.writeEvent to log these events. I'm not sure where they are being shown.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!